# Make Up Key Act As Shift Key

Tags: windows

The Lenovo Yoga has a pretty cramped keyboard that wedges an up arrow key right into where you'd expect the shift key to extend. It'd be nice if you could sacrifice the up arrow key to shift until you've adjusted to the new keyboard layout.

[image: Up arrow key occupying right-half of right shift key region]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this surprisingly simply with [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/download/).

```
Up::
Send {RShift down}
KeyWait Up
Send {RShift up}
return
```

This listens for the up arrow key, sends a right-shift held down, waits until the Up key is released, then sends a right-shift release. Simple!

If you're new to AutoHotKey, install it then right-click the icon and click "Edit this Script". Paste the above code in, save it in Notepad then right-click the app icon again and hit "Reload this Script". Off ya go.

Relevant docs/info:
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/11321-can-autohotkey-hold-down-a-key/

Comment: this can be done even easier with [sharpkeys](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)

Comment: Awesome, never heard of it, sounds like that'd be good as an Answer!